# Зафиксировать шапку таблицы от прокрутки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

На странице есть таблица на весь экран, хочу сделать так что бы когда таблица прокручивалась, шапка доходила до верха экрана и фиксировалась. Как это сделать?
Шапка находится в тегах `<thead></thead>`

Comment: Здравствуйте! Здесь конечно нужен ваш код, а именно: HTML код самой таблицы, с необходимыми стилями(CSS). Пока я вам справедливый минус ставлю, как добавите код, уберу минус. Всего вам доброго!

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov здесь не нужен код, он у всех HTML-таблиц примерно одинаковый, автор указал что шапка в thead — этого достаточно, ну а CSS этому вопросу просто никак не поможет

Comment: @andreymal Здравствуйте! Уверены вы в правильности своих слов? Сейчас здесь один ответ с тремя плюсами, и вот, там, и HTML, и CSS. Хотя по вашему CSS не нужен совсем. Итак, если один единственный ответ содержит и HTML и CSS, и автор ответа не поленился это написать. Тогда, что мешает автору вопроса поступить также и написать свой код? andreymal не могу вам за комментарий минус поставить, но тогда скажу просто. Минус ставлю вам, я с вами не согласен. Всего вам andreymal доброго!

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov я нигде не говорил, что HTML и CSS не нужны в ответе. Они не нужны только в вопросе.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov «что мешает автору вопроса поступить также и написать свой код?» — мешает отсутствие в этом какого-либо смысла. Если вы не знаете, как выглядит код таблиц, почитайте любой учебник по HTML и не минусуйте людей зазря :)

Comment: @andreymal На мой взгляд вы пишите удивительное. Так можно к массе всего написать: «А разве вы не знаете как выглядит ... ?». Здесь тогда можно к массе вопросов, такое оправдание написать. Минус, считаю заслуженный поставил, и вам бы поставил. У вас своя правда, у меня своя. На этом, считаю, здесь все. **Всего вам andreymal доброго!**

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov а по вашей логике получается, что в вопрос нужно дописать, что такое thead, что такое HTML, что такое тег, что такое таблица, что такое шапка, что такое экран. Я не считаю что это стоит делать. Если вы не знаете общеизвестные вещи — это проблемы ваши, а не вопроса. Как выглядит код таблиц, написано в любом учебнике по HTML; раз уж вы взялись реагировать на вопросы по HTML, пожалуйста, прочитайте сперва этот самый учебник. Такие вещи ещё позволительно не знать вопрошающему, а вот отвечающим вроде вас такие вещи знать просто обязательно.

Answer (score 5):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table-fixed-head {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  height: 100vh;
}

.table-fixed-head th,
.table-fixed-head td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 33.333vw;
}

.table-fixed-head thead {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #FDFDFD;
}

.table-fixed-head thead tr {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.table-fixed-head tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 30px);
}

.table-fixed-head tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-fixed-head">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title 1</th>
      <th>Title 2</th>
      <th>Title 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: эмм... что тут происходит, за счёт чего достигается такой эффект?

Answer (score 0):

За счет того что мы ломаем таблицу в tbody display:block и width: 100vw - ширина скроллбара. Из-за этого приходится задавать ширину ячеек th и td. тогда уж проще сделать вообще все на дивах.